# How to read from Response.OutputStream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, arrays, outputstream

I'm using `ServiceStack` to create a Service. In one of the methods I write some data in response's output stream like this: `await response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(Consts.DATA, 0, Consts.DATA.Length);` where data is a `byte[]`. Ok, now the problem is when using this service from a client and GET the `HttpResponseMessage` for the specified method, I don't know how to get the data out. I wan't to unit test that the actual response contains the data I passed when writing to output content.

(I've tried to ReadAsByteArray but it throws an exception. When reading as Stream or String I don't know how to make it a byte[] to compare it in the test with the excpected Consts.DATA byte array.)

I'm pretty new to the field, excuse my ignorance if i miss something. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code you use to fetch the data, specifically the HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: `var message = await client.SendAsync( new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "the-url"));`

Comment: Which class is client an instance of?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return your data like this? You can just return your MemoryStream and use appropriate ContentType header, described here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the typed client, you can do (from the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#support-for-native-built-in-response-types)):

As raw bytes:

```
byte[] responseBytes = client.Get<byte[]>("/poco/World");
var dto = responseBytes.FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
dto.Result //Hello, World
```

Or as a Stream:

```
using (Stream responseStream = client.Get<Stream>("/poco/World")) {
    var dto = responseStream.ReadFully()
        .FromUtf8Bytes()
        .FromJson<PocoResponse>();
    dto.Result //Hello, World
}
```

Or even access the populated HttpWebResponse object:

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = client.Get<HttpWebResponse>("/poco/World");

webResponse.Headers["X-Response"] //World
using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    var dto = sr.ReadToEnd().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
    dto.Result //Hello, World
}
```

You can also use untyped ServiceStack client to access raw response, it is described in the [documentation with samples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#accessing-raw-service-responses).

Answer (score 0):

Run your output stream through this static method:

```
    public static byte[] ReadFullStream(Stream st)
    {
        var lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock, ref lockTaken);
            var size = 0;
            var continueRead = true;
            var buffer = (byte[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), 0x10000);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (continueRead)
                {
                    size = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (size > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continueRead = false;
                    }
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken) { Monitor.Exit(_lock); }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: forgot, you'll need this defined at class scope:

```
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is load the data from an URL as a Stream and youre using a HttpClient you can just do this to get a stream back:

```
var result = await client.GetStreamAsync(URL);
```

I think you can also use GetResponseStream() on your HttpWebResponse.

```
 var result = message.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read response stream as follow-

```
      using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusDescription.ToUpper() == "OK" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseContent))
                    {
                        objFSLstGetAgent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectClass>(responseContent);
                    }
                }
```